# How to display limited records in django select box?

Tags: python, django

I would like to know to show limited records in django select field.I return queryset as like below syntax.

```
form.fields['team'].queryset = Teams.objects.exclude(selected_by_user = user.id)
```

But I have over 100k records. So I'm not able to show it in select box cause it's taking too much of loading time.

in template file should like below

```
{{ form.team|bootstrap }}
```

How to do this?

Comment: That depends, how do you decide what  gets shown?

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you can slice the results, it may be more helpful to use something like [typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) or [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) to fetch results based on what the user is entering with a separate ajax request.

Otherwise you may want to look into other ways of filtering down the results such as having a separate select box first to filter by results by first letter or similar